# Is it possible to add HTML form in Inno setup?

Tags: inno-setup

I have created a custom installer for a game. I need to update version of my installer with a new feature. The game needs to register to play online. So I need to embed register form from web page (or use HTML codes directly into Inno Setup pages after installation done. So people doesn't need to visit page and able to register play online via Inno Setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no native support for including a web page to Inno Setup installer. Neither I'm aware of any 3rd party extension that would support it.

---

Instead, you can code a custom installer page using the [`CreateInputQueryPage` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createinputquerypage) to query user registration details and send them to your web site.

A simple example:

```pascal
[Code]
var
  UserPage: TInputQueryWizardPage;
  
procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  UserPage := CreateInputQueryPage(wpWelcome,
    'Registration', 'Who are you?',
    'Please specify your name and username tor register, then click Next.');
  UserPage.Add('Name:', False);
  UserPage.Add('User name:', False);
end;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;

  if CurPageID = UserPage.ID then
  begin
    if (UserPage.Values[0] = '') or (UserPage.Values[1] = '') then
    begin
      MsgBox('You must enter your name and username.', mbError, MB_OK);
      Result := False;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  WinHttpReq: Variant;
  RegisterUrl: string;
begin
  if CurStep = ssDone then
  begin
    try
      RegisterUrl :=
        'https://www.example.com/register.php?' +
          Format('name=%s&username=%s', [UserPage.Values[0], UserPage.Values[1]])

      Log('Sending registration request: ' + RegisterUrl);

      WinHttpReq := CreateOleObject('WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1');
      WinHttpReq.Open('GET', RegisterUrl, False);
      WinHttpReq.Send('');

      Log('Registration report send result: ' +
          IntToStr(WinHttpReq.Status) + ' ' + WinHttpReq.StatusText);
    except
      Log('Error sending registration report: ' + GetExceptionMessage);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

(Note that this lacks URL-encoding of the data).

[image: Register]

---

Or simply open the registration form at the end of the installation in a web browser.

```
[Run]
Filename: "https://www.example.com/register.php"; \
    Description: "&Open registration form"; \
    Flags: shellexec runasoriginaluser postinstall
```

[image: Open web page]

Answer (score 2):

Create a new page in installer with embedded browser in it.

I recommend to use this component: https://code.google.com/p/inno-web-browser/

Usage is really simple: https://code.google.com/p/inno-web-browser/source/browse/trunk/Example.iss

When user advances to your (newly created) page, navigate to your website (which should be running somewhere on server).

Comment: I am not sure but I think TLama wrote that component?